# How securely is data deleted with IndexedDB?

Tags: web-browser

I'd like to understand how securely is data deleted when we request for its deletion using `.clear()`. I suspect it being weak. Is there a method available from the browser API (would write/delete junk cycles on same database object would give some protection ?)
My use-case is secret key persistence until manual deletion by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the operating system and file system. For instance, if it is BTRFS, then when you delete data, browser will save changed file, but BTRFS can instead keep all the blocks of the previous version of file unchanged and only create a copy of the changed block, modify it and save. Thus the previous version can easily be restored. It is not weakness. It is a benefit in case one needs to roll back the system to some previous state.

Also in case of other file systems the OS can decide to save the file or its part to a different place on the disk, so that previous version can still be completely or partially restored from the disk.

If you want to be sure that the data you deleted in IndexedDB cannot be found on the disk, you cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

IndexedDB is an [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) supported by [many browsers](https://caniuse.com/indexeddb). So, while one browser may be deleting it securely others may do differently.

I think most browsers use SQLite as backend for their indexedDB implementation. For instance you can view here [Firefox implementation of indexedDB](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/dom/indexedDB).

SQLite doesn't implement secure deletion of data by default (there is a [pragma](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_secure_delete) and a [compile option](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#secure_delete) that can be used to make it overwrite deleted data with zeroes). Thus, something removed from higher-level IndexedDB may still exist on the file providing the IndexedDB for the browser (and, once gone from there, we would have to inspect what the filesystem is doing).

I don't you should worry at this level about access to deleted IndexedDB contents through forensics. What you can do if you want to let the user delete it is to invalidate the stored data server-side, such as disabling the access token that was on IndexedDB or actually store the key symmetrically encrypted with a key quite-liberally-provided by the server until rotated.